# Python change environment with versions

Tags: python, virtualenv

Is it possible to change python version inside virtualenvironment. 
I know I can use `virtualenv -p <python-version>`, but I have to install  in system that version (I can't use that version from pyenv) and can't just switch it inside environment. I have to create difference environments for every version. Is it possible to do the same thing with pyenv, for example switch versions inside activated virtualenv, something like this:

```
(venv)...$: python --version #2.7.6
(venv)...$: pyenv local 3.3.5
(venv)...$: python --version #unfortunelly still 2.7.6, i need 3.3.5 in the same enviroment
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you must use `The --extra-search-dir option` .

**This option allows you to provide your own versions of setuptools and/or pip to use instead of the embedded versions that come with virtualenv.**

To use this feature, pass one or more `--extra-search-dir` options to virtualenv like this:

```
$ virtualenv --extra-search-dir=/path/to/distributions ENV
```

The `/path/to/distributions` path should point to a directory that contains setuptools and/or pip wheels.

virtualenv will look for wheels in the specified directories, but will use pip’s standard algorithm for selecting the wheel to install, which looks for the latest compatible wheel.

As well as the extra directories, the search order includes:

```
1.The virtualenv_support directory relative to virtualenv.py
2.The directory where virtualenv.py is located.
3.The current directory.
```

read more [here](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html#the-extra-search-dir-option)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for
`$ pyenv global <version>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).